# sysinternals ZoomIt How to keep annotations on the screen after exiting drawing mode

Tags: sysinternals

> ZoomIt from Microsoft Sysinternals suite is a screen zoom and
>   annotation tool for technical presentations that include application
>   demonstrations.

By default ZoomIt erase all annotations after exiting drawing mode, I want to keep those annotations on my screen after exiting drawing mode, so I can work and see them at the same time.